# "Access is denied" Run VB script from Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, shell, permissions, access-denied

I need to make an asynchronous job. In loop from MAIN.xlsm I want to call VB script (with different parameters) to open more Excel instances where `.refreshAll` method is executed. (This way I can open more files at once and don't need to wait on synchronous execution of VBA in Excel).

The last thing causing problem is permissions in Shell. To make it easier I simplified code (w/o loop & parameters). `Sub OpenShell` is in Excel VBA module. UAC is off, I am local admin on PC.

```vb
Sub OpenShell()
    strShell = "cmd.exe /k cscript " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\1.vbs"
    Shell strShell 
Exit Sub
```

VB script has only one line: `Wscript.Echo "Running"`

Result in shell: "Access is denied".

Comment: Note: If there are spaces in your path you need to enclose it in `""` or it will run into errors: `strShell = "cmd.exe /k cscript """ & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\1.vbs"""`

Comment: thx but again the same "Access is denied" as before....another hint?

Comment: What is the result of `Debug.Print strShell`? I tested it and it worked for me, so I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: you tried with elevated prompt?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ 'cmd.exe /k cscript "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\test\1.vbs"' My 1.vbs is nested here: C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\test\

Comment: @QHarr Not sure what it is... Can you adapt my code accordingly. I need to execute this task programmatically. No GUI. Thx

Comment: This should work. Syntax looks good, at least this works for me in my test. Is `XYZ` the user you are currently logged in with? If not make sure that the currently logged in user has the permissions to access this folder.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ "XYZ"... :) I just replaced my real id name for keeping me anonymous

Comment: @kabarto yes, of course. But my question was does it represent the username you are currently logged in with or does it represent another users username?

Comment: @Peh currently logged in user

Comment: Ah, the error probably doesn't come from the `OpenShell()` sub but from your `1.vbs`. Please also provide the code of the VBScript in your question.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ done, have a look on org. post

Comment: Must have to be some restriction with your computer. I still cannot reproduce it. I tested same file same location same code › Running. Is your VBScript still opened in editor? Make sure it is closed then.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is found the issue: McAfee is blocking the script...